# Router for Internet via VPN, HTTPS-Proxy or SSH

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, router

I'm curious if someone knows an answer to my quite special question.

I want to realize the following setup:

I have 1 static IP with (restricted) internet access via Ethernet. I want to get a router connected to this port which should be able to grant dhcp adresses and internet to at least 3 pcs. now comes the tricky part: because of port restrictions, NAT is not an option.

On the other hand I have a root server on which a HTTPS proxy (squid) is running and where i could setup a VPN server or SSH tunnel.
Is there a possibility (cheap one would be best as always^^) to let the router connect to my root server and forward the unrestricted internet to the 3 client PCs?

I read a bit in DD-WRTs documentation but couldn't come up with an answer to this specific question. also, I found this product http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=564, but I couldn't find an answer in its technical description either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can setup a VPN server (such as [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/overview.html)) on the external server and a VPN client on router ([DD-WRT seems to support OpenVPN](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN)). Then configure the router to route all traffic over the VPN. You will need to NAT the client machines either on the VPN server or the router.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should set up a pfSense box (or something like that) that will serve as a LAN-to-LAN VPN router, tunneling traffic back through your hosted server.

While SSH tunneling may work, it is very limited in what it can support. The same goes for a proxy server. With a full-fledged VPN (I'd recommend OpenVPN), you won't have any compatibility issues with certain applications like you would with the other options.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I looked at the pfSense homepage and the requirements are quite high, so I suppose I could not use this on an embedded device like a router. I also found tun2socks which basically does what I expect (reading the description). Do you think this would cause compatibility issues?